# Image Assets vue 2 dont showing on build

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vue-cli

I have a SPA project with this structure:

```
    public
      - css
      - data
      - images
    src
      - assets
      - components
      - plugins
        - components
        - images
     - views
```

And i have this script on package.json:

```
      "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
        "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
        "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e"
      }
```

inside of public/images folder i have the same content of plugins/images. When i set the images on components or views, i make something like:

```html
    <img src="../plugins/images/users/hanna.jpg" alt="user-img" class="img-circle">
```

These in dev mode works fine, but i can see when inspect the code runing that `src` attr is changed for `src="/img/hanna.jpg"`. This way, when ai run build script, the same prefix attr (/img/) are setted at all src attributes.

Because of this, any image is not show. And i can't find any help to set config for this.

My vue.config.js is:

```
    var webpack = require('webpack');

    module.exports = {
      lintOnSave: false,
      publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        ? 'https://XXXX.cloudfront.net/'
        : '/',
      productionSourceMap: false,
      filenameHashing: false,
      configureWebpack: {
        plugins: [
          new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            Chartist: "chartist",
            Raphael: "raphael"
          })
        ]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation is correct, if you do not see the photos it is because it probably does not expose those resources.

You must serve the "img" folder. This happens automatically in the development environment but you have to think about it in the production environment. You can also do this with a simple htaccess file

Comment: Can you explain that further? How does "expose those resources" work?

Comment: You must serve the "img" folder. This happens automatically in the development environment but you have to think about it in the production environment. You can also do this with a simple htaccess file

Comment: Please add all such explanation, especially about **how to do it actually**, to the answer itself, not to the comment section